Customizing OpenReview review form: how to fix the "The property Needs Ethics Review must NOT be present" error?
I use OpenReview for a conference and I need to customize the review form. I'm trying to add two fields about ethics on a review form in OpenReview.
I went to the Full Venue Configuration page, clicked on "Review stage", and added:
{
    "strengths": {
        "value": {
            "param": {
                "type": "string",
                "minLength": 1,
                "maxLength": 20000,
                "input": "textarea",
                "markdown": true
            }
        },
        "order": 5
    },
    "weaknesses": {
        "value": {
            "param": {
                "type": "string",
                "minLength": 1,
                "maxLength": 20000,
                "input": "textarea",
                "markdown": true
            }
        },
        "order": 6
    },
    
  "Needs Ethics Review": {
    "order": 7,
    "description": "Should this paper be sent for an in-depth ethics review? We have a small ethics committee that can specially review very challenging papers when it comes to ethical issues. If this seems to be such a paper, then please explain why here, and we will try to ensure that it receives a separate review.",
    "value": {
      "param": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "Yes",
          "No"
        ],
        "input": "radio"
      }
    }
  },
    
      "Ethical Concerns": {
        "order": 8,
        "description": "(Optional) Indicate your ethical concerns, if any. Leave this field blank if no ethical concerns.",
        "value": {
          "param": {
            "type": "string",
            "maxLength": 1000,
            "optional": true
          }
        }
      
    }
}


Adding the field weaknesses and the field strengths went fine. However, I get the error the field Needs Ethics Review and the field Ethical Concerns:

An error occurred while running the stage Review Stage your service request.
Error:
{
  "name": "MultiError",
  "message": "The property Needs Ethics Review must NOT be present (2024-08-04-10071000)",
  "status": 400,
  "errors": [
    {
      "name": "AdditionalPropertiesError",
      "status": 400,
      "message": "The property Needs Ethics Review must NOT be present",
      "details": {
        "path": "invitation/edit/invitation/edit/note/content",
        "additionalProperty": "Needs Ethics Review"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "AdditionalPropertiesError",
      "status": 400,
      "message": "The property Ethical Concerns must NOT be present",
      "details": {
        "path": "invitation/edit/invitation/edit/note/content",
        "additionalProperty": "Ethical Concerns"
      }
    }
  ],
  "details": {
    "reqId": "2024-08-04-10071000"
  }
}


What's the issue?
FYI, current review form.

The error message is very uninformative. Here's the fix, from the OpenReview documentation:

Use lowercase for the field names and underscores to represent spaces. The UI will auto-format the names, for example: supplementary_material -> Supplementary Material.

In my example:

Replace Needs Ethics Review with Needs_Ethics_Review
Replace Ethical Concerns with Ethical_Concerns

{
    "strengths": {
        "value": {
            "param": {
                "type": "string",
                "minLength": 1,
                "maxLength": 20000,
                "input": "textarea",
                "markdown": true
            }
        },
        "order": 5
    },
    "weaknesses": {
        "value": {
            "param": {
                "type": "string",
                "minLength": 1,
                "maxLength": 20000,
                "input": "textarea",
                "markdown": true
            }
        },
        "order": 6
    },
    "Needs_Ethics_Review": {
        "order": 7,
        "description": "Should this paper be sent for an in-depth ethics review? We have a small ethics committee that can specially review very challenging papers when it comes to ethical issues. If this seems to be such a paper, then please explain why here, and we will try to ensure that it receives a separate review.",
        "value": {
            "param": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                    "Yes",
                    "No"
                ],
                "input": "radio"
            }
        }
    },
    "Ethical_Concerns": {
        "order": 8,
        "description": "(Optional) Indicate your ethical concerns, if any. Leave this field blank if no ethical concerns.",
        "value": {
            "param": {
                "type": "string",
                "maxLength": 1000,
                "optional": true
            }
        }
    }
}

Result:

